# Multiplication of an array by one and other not working

Tags: java, android, arrays, int

First of all: I'm a beginner in programming and working on an assignment for school. A schoolmate and I are working on an application for a teacher, who has a site about physics.

We want to implement a validation of the e-mail adress + code. The first 6 characters from the email get a numeric value * a var ('sleutel') in my code. I used a method getNumber to say: a=1, b=2, c=3. I want to multiply the digits from that string by one and other. This is what the entered code should be, to advance.

For example: when you enter abc, getNumber converts it to 123, multiply by 'sleutel' gives me 51015 (1*5, 2*5, 3*5). And this is where it goes wrong: I want the following: 5*10*15.
But the codes gives me: 5*1*0*1*5(=0...).

Is there a (different) way how I can achieve this? Thank you in advance.

```
if (email_text.getText().length() > 0
                && code_text.getText().length() > 0) {
            final String userEmail = email_text.getText().toString()
                    .substring(0, Math.min(6, email_text.length()))
                    .toLowerCase();
            final String userCode = code_text.getText().toString();


            String validCode = "";
            int sleutel = 3;
            for (int i = 0; i < userEmail.length(); i++) {
                validCode += getNumber(userEmail.charAt(i)) * sleutel;
            }

            int res = 1;
            for (char digits : validCode.toCharArray()) {
                res *= (digits - '0');
            }
            final String validCode2 = Integer.toString(res);

            if (userCode.equals(validCode2)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Home.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            } else { // display toast}

private int getNumber(Character c) { return "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.-_@".indexOf(c) +1;
```

}

Comment: Shouldn't you just multiply your sleutel variable with value returned from getNumber method instead of using addition?

Comment: @MehmetSedatGüngör sorry I've been messing around with the code a long time (to see what is working) and yes it should be * instead. But then it's not working!

Comment: Can you show code of getNumber method?

Comment: @YoranY what should getNumber() function should return for `@_.` chars (valid for emails)?

Comment: Btw, your res integer can be 0 if validCode has at least one 0 digit in it and you are starting your intent based on this variable. You should take consider that condition also IMO.

Comment: @MehmetSedatGüngör I edited my answer, you can find getNumber there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `getNumber()` maps 'a' to 1, 'b' to 2, ... , '@' to 29, then the range of possible when multiplied by `sleutel` (3) would be 3-87. A `String` such as "abck" would be mapped to "12311", and when multiplied by `sleutel` would become "36933". But even if the code knows it's a 4 digit String there's no way it can know how it breaks down:

36933 could be 3*6*9*33=5346 (correct) or 36*9*3*3=2916 (incorrect) or 3*69*3*3=1863 (incorrect), etc.

Instead of storing each step as a `String`, here I do everything in one `for` loop:

```
if (email_text.getText().length() > 0 && code_text.getText().length() > 0) {
    final String userEmail = email_text.getText().toString().substring(0, Math.min(6, email_text.length())).toLowerCase();
    final String userCode = code_text.getText().toString();

    int sleutel = 3;
    long res = 1;
    for(int i=0; i<userEmail.length(); i++)    // loops through userEmail
       res *= getNumber(userEmail.charAt(i)) * sleutel;    // when the loop ends, res will have the correct value

    if (userCode.equals(Long.toString(res))) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Home.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {...} // display toast
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I already thought the answer would be something like this. But... when the lenght of userEmail > 6, validCode2 becomes zero. How can I fix this? Also, some emails give me negative numbers.

Comment: Just changed my method, this is much simpler, you don't even need any data structure to store intermediate steps. One `for` loop is used to generate `res`

Comment: The reason you're getting negative numbers is because an `int` has a maximum value of 2,147,483,647 (2^31 - 1). If `userEmail` is "@@@@@@" for example, then `res` should be (29*3)^6 = 433,626,201,009, way beyond the scope of an `int`. The solution would either be to alter your algorithm, or to simply make `res` a `long`, which has a max value of 2^63 - 1 = 9*(10^18), well above the max possible `res` value (433,626,201,009 from "@@@@@@")

Comment: Wow.. you seem to know much about this subject. Thank you very much for helping me out. Where did you learn this kind of stuff? (it's working btw)

Comment: I'm somewhat of a beginner myself actually but the internet is a great source of information. For example I didn't know all these numbers off the top of my head: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 0):

This following JavaSE application does what you need for the example you provided.

It's easy to adapt the code to your Android app.

You didn't clear out how it should behave with `@_.` chars in email.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(generateCodeFromEmail("abc"));
}

public static String generateCodeFromEmail(String email) {
    String emailSubstring = email.substring(0, Math.min(6, email.length())).toLowerCase();
    char[] chars = new char[emailSubstring.length()];
    email.getChars(0, emailSubstring.length(), chars, 0);
    int strotel = 5;
    int result = 1;

    for (char c : chars) {
        result *= ((int) c - 96) * strotel;
    }
    return String.valueOf(result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have edited my question and there you will find the getNumber method, which deals with @._ chars. But where do I need to put this inside my code?